# How to disable the builtin Python Interactive window support in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am mainly using `IPython` and I feel more comfortable in using a classic `IPython REPL` than the `VSCode` builtin `Python Interactive window`, therefore I would like to disable it, but I have no idea how.

I checked the [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) but I couldn't find any instructions on how to disable it.

At the moment I am using the [ipython extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HoangKimLai.ipython) and I am very happy with that.

[image]

Comment: don't use the `# %%` lines, then you don't get the interactive Python

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As stated in the document, it is precisely because of the use of "#%%".

So it wakes up the Jupyter code cells in vcscode.